# Quality Center: How to check if a test is already included in any requirement

Tags: quality-center, coverage, requirements-validation

How can I check that a specific Test Case is already included in any of the existing requirements? Currently I see no other way rather than going through all the requirements and trying to locate this test manually. However I believe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm closing this as it is too localised. This is a very specific feature discoverability problem with quality centre that can be answered already with a google search. If the site was full of these questions it would reduce the value of this site.

Comment: @Bruce McLeod Fact that I didn't find an answer for this simple question not here and not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, go to Test Plan and click on the desired Test Case. Locate the "Req Coverage" tab at the right top side of the screen. After clicking on the tab, a list of requirements which this test covers will appear.

Comment: Huh, why are you answering your own question ??

Comment: @Phil Kirkham Because I found the answer and wanted it to be available to the rest of the users here.